# Are there still no "simple analytical proofs" of Bloch's theorem in three dimensions?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

Section 2.1.2 of Sydney G. Davison and Maria Stęślicka's 1992 [Basic Theory of Surface States](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/basic-theory-of-surface-states-9780198518969?cc=tw&lang=en&) says:

> **2.1.2 Bloch theorem**
>
> The generalization of the Bloch-Floquet theorem to three dimensions is fairly obvious, and leads to the following form of the wave function
>
> $$\psi_\mathbf{k}(\mathbf{r}) = u_\mathbf{k}(\mathbf{r}) \exp(i \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}) \tag{2.11}\label{eq1} $$
>
> where $\mathbf{k}$ is the *wave vector* and the function $u_\mathbf{k}(\mathbf{r})$ has three three-dimensional periodicity of the crystal lattice, vis.,
>
> $$u_\mathbf{k}(\mathbf{r+\mathbf{a_n}}) = u_\mathbf{k}(\mathbf{r}).  \tag{2.12}\label{eq2} $$
>
> The vectors $\mathbf{a_n}$ may be expressed in terms of three primitive translation vectors $\mathbf{a_1}$, $\mathbf{a_2}$, $\mathbf{a_3}$,
>
> $$\mathbf{a_n} = n_1\mathbf{a_1} + n_2\mathbf{a_2} + n_3\mathbf{a_3}  \tag{2.13}\label{eq3} $$
>
> where $n_1$, $n_2$, $n_3$ are integers.
>
> Equation $\eqref{eq1}$ was first derived by Block (1928), and is known as *Bloch's theorem*. **Unfortunately, unlike the one-dimensional case, there is no simple analytical proof of this theorem.** However, it is possible to demonstrate, from the periodicity of the electron potential energy, namely,
>
> $$V(\mathbf{r}) = V(\mathbf{r} + \mathbf{a_n})  \tag{2.14}\label{eq4} $$
>
> that the electronic function has the form required by Bloch's theorem.

My question is about proofs of Bloch's theorem in three dimensions, analytical, simple, or otherwise.

Wikipedia's [Bloch_wave; Proof of Bloch's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_wave#Proof_of_Bloch%27s_theorem) addresses this, but I'm not sure if this is a proof, analytical, or simple. Perhaps it's more like a "demonstration" as discussed above.

**Question:** Are there still no "simple analytical proofs" of Bloch's theorem in three dimensions? If there are, what might one be? If not, what's the closest thing to one, where "simple" would be in my case most accessible for someone who's revisiting this circa 30 years post graduate.

---

**note 1:** Addressing [@insomniac's comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/536860/are-there-still-no-simple-analytical-proofs-of-blochs-theorem-in-three-dimens?noredirect=1#comment1215389_536860)

> Perhaps you should add to your question what the authors claim constitutes an analytic proof of Bloch theorem in the 1-d case

and trying to avoid reproducing the entire chapter here, the author says:

> 2.1.1 Bloch-Floquet theorem
>
> ...Solutions of ($\psi''(x) + f(x) \psi(x) = 0$) can be found with the help of a theorem which, in pure mathematics, is known as the Floquet (1883) theorem and, when applied to wave mechanics, is called *Bloch's theorem*. According to the Bloch-Floquet theorem, solutions... may be written in the form
>
> $$\psi(x) = \psi_k(x) = u_k(x) \exp(ikx)$$
>
> where...

Based on what I see in Proof Wiki's [Floquet's Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Floquet%27s_Theorem) and Wolfram Mathworld's [Floquet's Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FloquetsTheorem.html) I take it that section 2.1.1 is an analytical explanation or outline of the proof of the Floquet theorem *in one dimension* which the author says is another name for the Bloch theorem.

Comment: @DJKG Thanks! I'll defer to Oxford University Press editors and leave the comma in the block quote intact; if it's good enough for them, it's good enough for Stack Exchange. I've converted the offending a), b), c) enumeration to a flat sentence.

Comment: @-uhoh: I am no mathematician (hence, not really an authority on what constitutes an "analytic proof"), but I am pretty convinced by the first part of the Wiki "proof" (the part that shows that a simultaneous eigenfunction of all lattice translation operators must be of the Bloch form). I also agree that the fact that $H$ commutes with all possible lattice translations implies that we must have simultaneous eigenfunctions of H and lattice translation operators, which, by the first part, must be of the Bloch form. To me, that is a "proof"

Comment: Perhaps you should add to your question what the authors claim constitutes an analytic proof of Bloch theorem in the 1-d case.

Comment: @insomniac in hopes that you can sleep a bit easier I've tried to at least address that last comment in **note 1**. ;-)

Comment: This statement doesn't make any sense to me. Any solid state course worth the name will of course show a simple analytical proof of Bloch's theorem! As source, I cite any book that uses Bloch's theorem... except for this one, apparently.

Comment: Do the authors give the "simple analytical proof" for the 1D case? I don't really understand why that "demonstration that the electronic function has the necessary form" isn't the proof of the Bloch's theorem.

Comment: Perhaps they're using a very restrictive definition of "simple analytical", where they reject any use of ideas from linear algebra, i.e. maybe they want a derivation using only facts stated in freshman calculus.

Comment: @knzhou perhaps so. Might "facts stated in freshman calculus" be sufficient for a proof in 1 dimension but not in three dimensions?

Comment: Perhaps, but only because freshman calculus is very limited... by those standards there's no "simple analytical" proof of anything in more than one dimension, because freshman calculus is single-variable.

Comment: @uhoh The sleep feels like it is permanently gone :/ But given the state of the world, can we really blame my sleep for going AWol? But perhaps there may still be a chance ... If you could summarize the content of *Floquet theorem* in an easy to understand manner ... ;)